# what is the difference between Convolutional Nets and a Convolutional layer?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

need to know the difference between the Convolutional layers and a Convolutional nets.

when i searched the web i found that the Convolutional layers is the first layer which is the input.. is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with the basics of neural networks, especially what a layer in a neural network is.

A convolutional layer is just a certain type of layers in a neural network - so just a layer.

A convolutional network is a neural network which contains conventional layers.

So a convolutional layer is a part of a whole, where the whole thing is a convolutional network.

Comment: is the convolutional layer is the input (first) layer only?

Comment: You can have convolutional layers as first layer. But mostly you have stacked convolutional layers. E.g. 3 Convolutional layers -> Max Pooling Layer -> Again 3 Convolutional layers -> Max Pooling Layer....
So most convolutional layers are not the first layer.

Comment: so what is describes the convolutional  layer?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'describe', please clarify.

Comment: what is the Ingredients of the convolutional  layer?